# What happens underneath append function?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, ml

I got an implementation for `append` function in OCaml, but it seems confused to me

```
let rec append = function
| [] -> fun y -> y
| h :: t -> fun y -> h :: (append t y)
```

What is the purpose of the `fun y` in this case ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `append` is `'a list -> 'a list -> 'a list`. You can look at this as a function that takes two lists and returns a list. But (as is idiomatic in OCaml) the function is defined using [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying). So at the basic level, `append` takes a first list and returns a function of type `'a list -> 'a list`. The returned function takes the second list and prefixes the first list to it (returning the result).

The value `fun y -> y` is the function that `append` returns when the first list is empty. If you think about it, this makes sense. If the first list is empty, the second list will be returned unchanged. In other words, the returned function is no different at all from an identity function (specialized for applying to lists).

The second case returns the value `fun y -> h :: (append t y)`. This is similar, but a little more complicated. The returned function needs to do some actual appending. It does this by (recursively) appending the supplied second list (`y`) to the tail of the first list (`t`), then adding the head of the first list (`h`) to the front of that.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like the `fun`, you can rewrite the function like this

```
let rec append x y = match x with
| [] -> y
| h :: t -> h :: append t y
```